# Changing variables with commands discord.js

Tags: discord.js

How can I toggle between false/true a variable's value with a command

my code

```
var tagdetect = true;
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === 'tagdetect'){
  if (args[1] === 'true'){
    
  }
}

if (tagdetect){

    if (message.mentions.users.has('id')){
      client.TagİDAlgılayıcı.get('nick').execute(message, args);
      }
```

i am using a command handler, i want to do something like `{prefix}tagdetect true/false`

Comment: Hey, can you please go into more detail about what you're trying to achieve. i.e example of the command (like !ping => returns bots ping => Bots Ping: 200ms) im a bit confused on what you want done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tagdetect` is the variable you want to switch, you can use two if statements to switch the boolean's state based on user input.

```js
if (args[1] === 'true'){
    tagdetect = true;
} else if (args[1] === 'false'){
    tagdetect = false;
} else {
    // User has given an invalid setting, let them know by sending an error message.
}
```

The comment is just there to let you know what you should add.

Comment: yes i want to change ```tagdetect```

i changed the code like this but i always keep saying somethin is wrong
```var tagdetect = true;
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === 'tagdetect'){
  if (args[1] === 'true'){
    tagdetect = true;
      message.channel.send('Changed to true');
  }else if (args[1] === 'false'){
    tagdetect = false;
     message.channel.send('Changed to false');
  } else {
    message.channel.send('somethin is wrong');
  }

}```

Comment: Can you add this line in the `else` statement? `console.log(args[1]);` The argument might be returning something else. @nick